# Running a script for many files of the same extension and writing the results to a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, glob

I'm trying to write a script to extract data from a number of files in a directory with the extension ".tp6" and then write all of that data to a single text file.

It's able to get data from each file correctly and print them to the terminal, but I haven't been able to 'pass' each data point to another function that writes it to a text file.

Any ideas? Thank you!

```
import glob
import os
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
dir_path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
os.chdir(dir_path)


def main():
    for file_path in glob.glob('*.tp6'):
        uncovext(file_path)

def main2():
    for file_path in glob.glob('*.tp6'):
        totext(uncovext)


#find and print data from each .tp6 file - this part works correctly
def uncovext(file_path):
    for line in open(file_path):
        if line.startswith(' UNCONVOLVED INTEGRATED RADIANCE'):
            text = line[36:47]
            number = float(text) * 10000
            print('%.3f' % number)

def totext(uncovext):
    with open("output.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(uncovext)
        f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    main2()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it was a matter of naming: if you change your input parameter of totext function to p_uncovext for example, it should work. You need also to call the function to text on your loop.

```
import glob
import os
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
dir_path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
os.chdir(dir_path)

def main():
    for file_path in glob.glob('*.tp6'):
        uncovext(file_path)

#find and print data from each .tp6 file - this part works correctly
def uncovext(file_path):
    for line in open(file_path):
        if line.startswith(' UNCONVOLVED INTEGRATED RADIANCE'):
           text = line[36:47]
           number = float(text) * 10000
           totext('%.3f' % number)

def totext(p_uncovext):
    with open("output.txt", "a") as f:
       f.write(p_uncovext)
       f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems. First `uncovext` doesn't save the data it parses from the input file. After printing to the screen, it is just thrown away. You could collect it into a list and return that for further processing. Then, you call the writer in a second function and you don't have any way for `main` to let `main2` know what the data is.

An easy fix is a single function that calls `uncovext` and uses its result to call `totext`.

```
import glob
import os
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
dir_path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
os.chdir(dir_path)


def main():
    for file_path in glob.glob('*.tp6'):
        totext(uncovext(file_path))

#find and print data from each .tp6 file - this part works correctly
def uncovext(file_path):
    output = []
    for line in open(file_path):
        if line.startswith(' UNCONVOLVED INTEGRATED RADIANCE'):
            text = line[36:47]
            number = float(text) * 10000
            output.append('%.3f\n' % number)
    return output

def totext(uncovext):
    with open("output.txt", "a") as f:
        f.writelines(uncovext)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You could also rewrite your parser as a generator and write code that I find more self-explanatory (that's just me though...)

```
def main():
    with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
        for file_path in glob.glob('*.tp6'):
            f.writelines(uncovext(file_path))

#find and print data from each .tp6 file - this part works correctly
def uncovext(file_path):
    for line in open(file_path):
        if line.startswith(' UNCONVOLVED INTEGRATED RADIANCE'):
            text = line[36:47]
            number = float(text) * 10000
            yield '%.3f\n' % number
```